# View.getId() works while button.getId() dosen't

Tags: java, android, button, view, onclick

I have implemented a mediaplayer in android which plays different files with the help of different buttons.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Button button;
public void play(View view)
{

 int id  = view.getId();
 String ourId = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);

 mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,getResources().getIdentifier(ourId,"raw","com.example.demo"));
 mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Above code gives correct output while

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Button button;
public void play(View view)
{

 int id  = button.getId();
 String ourId = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);

 mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,getResources().getIdentifier(ourId,"raw","com.example.demo"));
 mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Crashes the app.

If I am clicking the button then I should take button's id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
int id  = button.getId();
```

crashes your app because `button` is not initialized.
Change to this:

```
button = (Button) view;
int id  = button.getId();
```

With this code `view` is cast to a `Button` and this is assigned to the variable `button`.
So `button` is initialized properly and is not `null`.
This does not mean that you have to go through this procedure.
If all you need is the `id` then do it with your code that works, without casting the variable `view` to a `Button`. The returned id from:

```
int id  = view.getId();
```

is correct.